# How do i change the password for root using webmin, where i have no more access as root?

Tags: fedora, centos, rhel, sudo, root

I changed the root password, using `webmin` it shows me successfully done.

```
$ uname -a
Linux .com 2.6.18-194.11.4.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 21 05:04:09 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ echo -e "newPassword\nnewPassword" | passwd root
```

now i am logged in via ssh and trying to sudo -s or sudo -
it says `Sorry, try again.`

Why i cant sudo -s login as root with valid password?
or sudo root commands?

EDIT:

```
> cat /etc/sudoers
/sbin/iwconfig, /sbin/mii-tool
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep = "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR \
                        LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME \
                        LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION \
                        LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC \
                        LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS \
                        _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you suppose to enter the password of user that you are trying to sudo from and make sure user has proper sudo access in `visudo` (/etc/sudoers)

Comment: Using WebMin i am logged in as root, i changed the password, then i tried to ssh to the machine as another user, i am logged in, now via ssh trying to sudo - or sudo -s with new password for root but its failing.

Comment: Please see EDIT the /etc/sudoers

Comment: what if you try `su -`